# What is "You need a premium license to create or run flows in an environment under Power Protect."?

Tags: power-automate, licensing

[image]

My customer send me this picture. I have no idea what is it and why this is happen.

As I know, user need premium license for using some connectors, dataverse and special ability like connect to on-premise data source.

I don't know what is Power Protect and relationship between it and premium license.

I google this problem and no result that can answer that.

I want to know what is it and why this is happen.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a platform error, I'm experiencing it too without any relevant change of the tenant \ company account.

There is a ticket opened on the microsoft support platform I'm monitoring their thread. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Invalid-Error-Environment-under-Power-Protect/td-p/2274957